# SSH prompts with wrong host key/fingerprint

Tags: linux, ssh

Using SSH to connect to a server (running Oracle Linux 7.9) I have set up, and I wanted to replace the original key pair I used with a different one. I am able to connect to the server using the new key pair without any apparent issue; however, whenever I connect (via OpenSSH in Windows CMD), I am still prompted with the fingerprint/randomart of the old key:

```
Host key fingerprint is SHA256:RCVRSnN6hl97h8+UgNobAPK6WTeymGpKhYTtKYp1npU
+---[ECDSA 256]---+
|     . .*++      |
|..    oo.B  .    |
|...    .=.o...   |
|....  .o ++. ....|
|..+...EoS+.o. o.o|
|oo.o o* + . o. = |
|o.  o= .   .    o|
|.  ..            |
| .o.             |
+----[SHA256]-----+
```

I have erased the old key pair from the server in all the locations I know it exists, checked the host key files in `/etc/ssh/` (which do contain the new key), tried erasing/refreshing my `known_hosts` file and some settings in my `config` file, but I am still prompted with the old key whenever I connect. I am inexperienced with SSH and Linux, so I'm sure there's something I'm missing here. How can I get it to prompt a connection with the new key pair?

Comment: May seem a redundant question, did you restart sshd?

Comment: @JaromandaX I believe I did. I used `sudo systemctl restart sshd`, which is the command I found for doing so on Redhat Linux.

Comment: Another, though unlikely, cause might be what it says: you have a MitM (intended on unintended), i.e. you are connecting *not* to the server you think and where you erased a key. Check your server logs.

Comment: *What* key pair are you thinking about?

Comment: the personal key pair you use to connect to a server is completely separate from the host key.

Answer (score 0):

%USERPROFILE%.ssh\ folder
'known_hosts' file on your windows system should have the known host keys for systems. - if you connect to a system for which you dont have a host key saved, you get a prompt.

id_rsa, id_dsa, id_ecdsa, id_ed25519 and perhaps some others, are the private key files for your keypair and corresponding  .pub is the public key file for that pair. - the line in .pub needs to go to the authorized_keys file in ~/.ssh/ folder in the target system.

seeing as you are replacing a keypair, did you remove the pub part of your old keypair from the target systems ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file ?

Comment: Yes, the authorized_keys file only has the new public key.